# sqlite-nodejs3: How do I notify nodejs when sqlite trigger has been triggered?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Here is what I need:

1. Nodejs creates a trigger in sqlite db (using node-sqlite3 module)
2. Trigger, well, gets triggered.
3. Nodejs process gets notified of that.

Here is what I am exloring:

1. Is it possible to supply a js callback when creating a trigger?
2. If not, is there an event in nodejs that I can listen to?
3. If not, can I use RAISE() in sqlite and catch it in nodejs?
4. What other possibilities are there? Perhaps have sqlite write to a socket?

Any wise man out there to nudge me in a right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for the 'trace' event emitted from the sqlite module. There is currently no way to intercept or stop queries in the module, so the most you can do is listen for this event which is emitted immediately when a query is executed and create your logic from there.

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Debugging

Comment: Haha, how did I stumble upon such an old question!